# Sending NodeJs Axios requests via Fiddler

Tags: node.js, axios, fiddler

I am using Windows + Visual studio code to developer a Node JS API. I am using Axios to submit rest requests from NodeJs to third party API's.

I would like to inspect the packets sent from my Node server to the third party  backend via Fiddler, however I have been having a hard time getting Axios to proxy through 127.0.0.1 port 8888.

Ideally it would be an easy global variable to set to turn on/off the proxy. the thing I have tried is:

```
axios.defaults.proxy = { host: "127.0.0.1", port:8888}

axios.defaults.proxy = { host: "127.0.0.1", port:8888, protocol: "http"}

axios.post(url: <api>, {post:data}, {proxy: {host: "127.0.0.1", "8888"} });
```

and a alot of different variations of the above. when the proxy is on, it won't complete the request.

Answer (score 4):

Is the server you are trying to reach using `https`? This is a problem with `axios` that they seem to be having trouble solving.

A workaround that will allow you to proxy through Fiddler is to use an HTTPS-over-HTTP tunnel. Jan Molak wrote [this nice article](https://janmolak.com/node-js-axios-behind-corporate-proxies-8b17a6f31f9d) about the scenario of sending a request to an `https` server through an `http` proxy. The following code has worked for me when running requests through Fiddler:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const tunnel = require('tunnel');

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  httpsAgent = tunnel.httpsOverHttp({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8888,
  }),
  proxy: false,
});

axiosInstance.post(/* ... */);
```

Comment: can't say how long I was searching for a solution... thank you!